# Check if shape is already in space (overlapping issue)

Tags: python

So I’m doing a tic tac toe using the the CMU course in python and I want to figure out
If there is already a shape either circle or rectangle. How can you stop your mouse when you click on a box/space that already has a shape inside.

If you look in the picture. I clicked on the square already there and it put a red circle OVER the blue square. I want this from not happening. I want it so that "If I click on a pre existing shape, it doesn't put a new shape".
Thanks, any help is appreciated

Using
CMU
Carnegie Melon University CS course
P.S (Since this is a different way of python using CMU, they have certain functions) I attached a picture of that as well.
[Code and what the Tic Tac Toe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC2Ks.jpg)
[Python Functions in CMU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W79ab.png)

I've been trying to figure out how and what to use in terms of functions. I just don't understand this overlapping thing.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell by the image you have attached, you are effectively using a dictionary for storing the game state. The keys are tuples with x and y coordinates, and values are string "red", "blue" or "" (empty)

So, regarding the question you pose, you may want something like this:

```
def click(x, y, color):
    if table.get(x,y) != "":
        return
    table[x,y] = color
```

You basically check if your dictionary has a non-empty string for certain coordinates before putting a shape to it.

Don't hesitate to let me know if this helped, or further clarification is needed

Comment: Thank you for this, I went ahead and tried this, it worked. Although now the only shape being recognized / placed is the red circle. I went ahead and linked all the code I have so far. Although it wont run, it'll show you what I've got so far.
Visit https://replit.com/@GA6th/AgreeableMildMetadata#main.py

Comment: I haven't been able to find any `click(...)` calls in the code you have provided so I caanot do much to help you from this point